# How to create accurate nanosecond delay in a pthread and how to run a pthread part of the program without interruption?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am a beginner in C programming. In the following code, we have two pthreads. I want one of them to be delayed at the user's choice after the two pthreads are synchronized. I want this delay to be as accurate as possible. In the following code I have done this but the exact amount of delay does not occur.

But I also have another question, and that is how can I force a pthread to run a certain part of the program from start to finish without interruption.

Thank you in advance.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/random.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>

pthread_cond_t cond;
pthread_mutex_t cond_mutex;
unsigned int waiting;
struct timeval timeZero, timeOne, timeZeroBase, timeOneBase;
struct timespec tim, tim2;
int flag = 0;

void synchronize(void) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cond_mutex);
    if (++waiting == 2) {
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    } else {
        while (waiting != 2)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &cond_mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cond_mutex);
}

void *threadZero(void *_) {
    // ...
    synchronize();
    gettimeofday(&timeZeroBase, 0);
    if(flag == 0)
        nanosleep(&tim, &tim2);
    gettimeofday(&timeZero, 0);
    timeZero.tv_usec = timeZero.tv_usec - timeZeroBase.tv_usec;
    // ...
    return NULL;
}


void *threadOne(void *_) {
    // ...
    synchronize();
    gettimeofday(&timeOneBase, 0);
    if(flag == 1)
        nanosleep(&tim, &tim2);
    gettimeofday(&timeOne, 0);
    timeOne.tv_usec = timeOne.tv_usec - timeOneBase.tv_usec;
    // ...
    return NULL;
}


int main(void) {
    pthread_t zero, one;
    tim.tv_sec  = 0;
    tim.tv_nsec = 50;
    printf("Declare the number of function (0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d", &flag);
    pthread_create(&zero, NULL, threadZero, NULL);
    pthread_create(&one, NULL, threadOne, NULL);
    // ...
    pthread_join(zero, NULL);
    pthread_join(one, NULL);
    printf("\nReal delay (ns): %lu\n", (timeZero.tv_usec - timeOne.tv_usec));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is an "_accurate nanosecond delay_"? ± how much? I think you can forget about using any kind of `sleep` function though. Busy-waiting is probably a better option.

Comment: When you say "nanosecond delay" do you mean a *single* nanosecond? That's not really possible. Neither are accuracy on any multitasking system. If you need timing accuracy in single nanosecond resolution you need a real-time system.

Comment: You are asking a lot from the operating system. The best bet you have is to bind the thread to a specific CPU core and have all there threads (on the entire operating system) restricted from using that core. You might want to use a real-time operating system. None of this is a beginner topic.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, I meant to be able to delay a few nanoseconds. For example, 50 nanoseconds or 100 nanoseconds or more. But this delay should be as accurate as possible. In the above code, the delay does not happen exactly and I do not know what to do.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, I mean, the delay is as accurate as possible. I know that it is not completely possible for me, that's why I asked how I could make a pthread run part of the program without interruption

Comment: @Cheatah, Yes, that's exactly the solution, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: A low level busy wait can achieve an active sleep lasting for dozens of ns on modern x86 processors. Still, the OS can schedule another thread (*context switches*) at any moment and you cannot prevent that by default on mainstream OS. A busy wait consume a lot the available resources since the OS is not aware that the thread is sleeping and will not schedule directly other threads resulting in more unexpected context switches at critical moments. This is why real-time is needed in that case.

Comment: What system exists that implements pthreads while at the same time implementing nanosecond real-time accuracy? Hint: it ain't a bloody Linux PC.

Comment: @mehran On my machine, even if I busy-wait in a loop and having calibrated an offset, I have a hard time staying within ± 50 ns of the requested sleep time and requested sleeps below < 200 ns will become ~200 ns sleeps using that approach (on my computer).

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, 200 ns and more is good for my work. how can I do it? I using ubuntu 18.04 and CPU intel core i7.

Comment: @mehran Ok, I've added an example. I hope it works on your machine too.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, Thank you very much, I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that may increase accuracy is to busy-wait instead of sleeping.

I've made a function called `mysleep` that takes a `struct timespec*` containing the requested sleep time. It checks the current time and adds the requested sleep time to that - and then just spins until the current time `>=` the target point in time.

Note though: It's not guaranteed to stay within any accuracy. It will *often* be rather ok, but sometimes when the OS puts the thread on hold, you'll see spikes in the measured time. If you are unlucky, the calibration will have one of these spikes in it and then *all* your sleeps will be totally off. You can run the calibration routine 100 times and then pick the median value to make that unfortunate circumstance very unlikely.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

static long calib; // used for calibrating mysleep()

void mysleep(const struct timespec *req) {
    struct timespec tp, now;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp); // get current time point

    // add the requested sleep time and remove the calibrated value
    tp.tv_sec += req->tv_sec;
    tp.tv_nsec += req->tv_nsec - calib;

    if(tp.tv_nsec > 999999999) {
        tp.tv_nsec -= 1000000000;
        ++tp.tv_sec;
    } else if(tp.tv_nsec<0) {
        tp.tv_nsec += 1000000000;
        --tp.tv_sec;
    }

    // busy-wait until the target time point is reached: 
    do {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
    } while(now.tv_sec < tp.tv_sec ||
            (now.tv_sec == tp.tv_sec && now.tv_nsec < tp.tv_nsec));
}

struct timespec get_diff(const struct timespec *start, struct timespec *end) {
    struct timespec temp;
    if((end->tv_nsec - start->tv_nsec) < 0) {
        temp.tv_sec = end->tv_sec - start->tv_sec - 1;
        temp.tv_nsec = 1000000000 + end->tv_nsec - start->tv_nsec;
    } else {
        temp.tv_sec = end->tv_sec - start->tv_sec;
        temp.tv_nsec = end->tv_nsec - start->tv_nsec;
    }
    return temp;
}

// A non-scientific calibration routine
void calibrate() {
    struct timespec start, end, sleep = {0};
    calib = 0;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    mysleep(&sleep);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    struct timespec diff = get_diff(&start, &end);
    calib = (diff.tv_sec * 1000000000 + diff.tv_nsec) / 2;
}

int main() {
    calibrate(); // must be done before using mysleep()

    // use mysleep()
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vc6hnsWac)

Possible output (with a spike):

```
calib=157
should be close to 1000:  961
should be close to 1000:  931
should be close to 1000:  906
should be close to 1000:  926
should be close to 1000:  935
should be close to 1000:  930
should be close to 1000:  916
should be close to 1000:  932
should be close to 1000:  124441
should be close to 1000:  911
```